# Return arbitrary value type in Object

Tags: typescript

If I have an object with many keys and each value in each key has different value type

```
type keys = 'typeA' | 'typeB' | ... | 'typeZZZ'
const obj = {
 'typeA': typeA,
 'typeB': typB,
...
'typeZZZ': typeZZZ
}

const destruct = (key: keys): /* what's the return type I can specify? */ => {
  return obj[key] // <- how should I narrow type here?
}

const typeA = destruct('typeA') // <- I want this value type to be `typeA` without using as or if statement
```

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `key` generic and only accept a key of `obj`.

```
const destruct = <K extends keyof typeof obj>(key: K): typeof obj[K] => {
  return obj[key]
}
```

The return type would then be `obj[K]`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=14#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIDWtIGd4F54HIpwILbwA%20OesAQkabjLAFqPaigDGA9gHarjzsBGAK0zwA3qDJ1CALngAiAIZyANBNpwqsgAyqQkuI3rZZnWAHd4AEQXhYACgCUoAL4sQHbrwAmsHgCcAV1ZeLAAeAGl4WAAPW04vdGRIdgAzeHJUviEAPjsk2XCHWQy0gUEAbXCAXUxssQl4P1hwAL9OLIqkqpc3Dx50qREffyDwO3VKbAcgA)

Comment: wow that's cool. thanks. I'll make it best answer after 5 min (there is time constraints )